# php check email already in database table

Tags: php

hi there im a little new to all of this so please bear with me.

I am trying to have a form that registers first, last, email into a table. if the email already exists id like to divert to a page and update the timestamp in the record for that email address. im not sure where to start. thanks in advance

edit: to clarify the goal here is

1.person A enters their details, if there is no record of their email address then a new record is created, timestamped and they proceed to the next page

2. person B enters their details, they have registered before, the database updates their records timestamp and they proceed to the next page

```
// Attempt insert query execution
try{
    // Create prepared statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sessions (first, last, email) VALUES (:first, :last, :email)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    // Bind parameters to statement
    $stmt->bindParam(':first', $_REQUEST['first']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':last', $_REQUEST['last']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_REQUEST['email']);

    // Execute the prepared statement
    $stmt->execute();
    header('Location: stream.php');
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Close connection
unset($pdo);
```

Comment: If your column is set with constraint it will restrict you, beside this  you can just try retrieve the record using the incoming email if found restrict from php side and update the timestamp.

Comment: Check if the user exists using a `SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE email=:email`.

Comment: hi and thanks for your answers. to put this another way im really new to all of this lol so if you could maybe help me with the recommended code and where to place it in what I have above that would be really appreciated

Comment: But if you are new, you should learn. So start with the pseudo. `if select email then update timestamp else insert session`. You have the code to insert, so the others shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Surprisingly nobody suggests `REPLACE INTO` or `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP how to check for email already in MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606304/php-how-to-check-for-email-already-in-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first set the `email` field in the database table as `UNIQUE` key.

Then, replace your SQL statement with:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (first, last, email) VALUES (:first, :last, :email)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE session_timestamp=NOW()
```

which I assume the Timestamp field you mentioned is named as `session_timestamp`.

The SQL statement inserts a new session row into the table when email does not exist in the table; otherwise, if the email already exists, it updates the timestamp field with current time. You do not require to forward to another page for another database action, which will:

1. make your code difficult to manage
2. waste loading time

Reference [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Yes, it is better to use one query, only issue will be if he wants to reuse the email duplication validation he can not use it, but rarely that will come.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu That's just an opinion. I would never trust the database structure for my domain's logic.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden yes, may be you would like to choose already existing structure because will reduce effort, there can be several option to go with, based on requirement and opinion.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I'm not talking about existing structures or reduced effort. I would not advice to hard-code domain logic in the database.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden oh! yes that is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

create a function using this code and call that before insert to check if email already exists. I believe for registration and updating email address you need to check if email already exists, so you can also reuse it.
I assume

You have pdo object

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

then use

function email_exists($pdo, $email){
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE email=:email");
    $stmt->execute(['email' => $email]); 
    if ($stmt->fetch()){
       return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please try to go through the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), it will help you getting everything done.

Comment: still incorrect. `$pdo` is inaccessible in this function.

Comment: @Raptor I have added $pdo as parameter to function. I would also like to suggest to create a class so that pdo object  will be avaialble through out the class and using $this->pdo, he can do the job.

Comment: Maybe, but it really depends on the overall code structure. If the code is just a tiny script, creating a class to wrap the whole thing up is too much.

Comment: @Raptor yes, but my assumption is at least he will b having create, insert, select, delete, update, so wrapping these makes sense.